# What is the best way to implement the x.224 OSI COTS protocol on Linux

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel, protocols, osi

I need to make an old Linux box running 2.6.12.1 kernel communicate with an older computer that is using:

ISO 8602 Datagram  (connectionless service) 1987 12 15 (1st Edition)
ISO 8073 Class 4 (connection oriented service)
These are using "Inactive Network Layer" subset. (I am pretty sure this means I do not have to worry about routing. The two end points are hitting each other with their mac addresses.)

I have a kernel module that implements the connectionless part. In order to get the connection oriented service operational, what is the best approach? I have been taking the approach of adding in the struct proto_ops .connect, .accept, .listen functions to my existing connectionless driver by referring to the tcp implementation.

Maybe there is a better approach? I am spending a lot of time trying to decide what the tcp code is doing and then deciding if that is relevant to my needs. For example, the Nagle algorithm isn't needed because I don't have small bits of data being transmitted. In addition, there are probably a lot of error recovery and flow control stuff I don't need because I know the data that the two endpoints are transmitting and how frequently they transmit it. My plan is to implement this first with whatever simplistic (if any) packet retransmission, sequencing, etc.. to the point where my wireshark looks similar to the wireshark capture I have from the live system. Then try mine against the real thing and then add in whatever error recovery/retransmit stuff seems necessary. In other words, it is a pain in the rear trying to determine what is the guts of the tcp/stream implementation that I want to copy vs the extra error correction/flow control stuff that I might never need.

I found \net\core\stream.c which says:
 *     Generic stream handling routines. These are generic for most
 *     protocols. Even IP. Tonight 8-).
 *     This is used because TCP, LLC (others too) layer all have mostly
 *     identical sendmsg() and recvmsg() code.
 *     So we (will) share it here.

This suggested to me that maybe there might be a simpler stream thingy that I can start from. Can someone recommend a more basic streams driver that I should start from instead of tcp?

Is there any example code that provides a basic stream implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I made a user level library to implement the protocol providing my own versions of open/read/write/select etc. If anyone else cares, you can find me at http://pnwsoft.com

Do not attempt to use openss7. It is a total waste of time.